# Properly disposing of Bitmap object

Tags: c#, winforms, object, bitmap, dispose

I am drawing images in a C# Winforms panel with:

```
private void DrawPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawOnPanel(e.Graphics);
}
```

The called method takes an existing image from my resources (myImage), gives it to another method which resizes the image and returns the resized image so it can be drawn.

```
public static void DrawOnPanel(Graphics g)
{
    var _resizedImage = ResizeImage(Resources.myImage);
    g.DrawImage(_resizedImage, destX, destY);

    // ... several other images resized & manipulated then drawn

}
```

The resize image function is:

```
public Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image)
{
    int scale = 3;
    var destImage= new Bitmap(image.Width * scale, image.Height * scale);
    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;

    using var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes();
    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
    }
    return destImage;
}
```

The program keeps calling DrawPanel.Invalidate() in its loop.
I am detecting a memory leak each time DrawPanel.Invalidate() is called. The memory consumption is rising steadily until the GC takes care of it. While this isn't a game breaking problem, I'm still wondering where and how should I dispose of my objects in the above code.
I tried using `using var _resizedImage = ResizeImage(Resources.myImage);` in the above `DrawOnPanel` method but the program returns an error `System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'`. If I remove `using` there is no error.

Comment: Please, post code that makes sense. Also, you don't need any of that: assign the Resource Image to a Field object or Collection, then use the Graphics object to draw the Image resized. There's an overload for it. Dispose of the Image when the Form closes. -- Keep in mind that Resources is a Factory (if that comes from `Properties.Resources`), it creates a **new Image Object** each time you ask for one.

Comment: `but the program returns an error here the second time I invalidate the screen.` https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1330430245384679424?s=20

Comment: We need to see where `destImage` is declared. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: (Made some corrections to the code above, destImage is declared at beginning of ResizeImage method.) The problem is in the using statement in the DrawOnPanel method. When I run the program it returns a parameter not valid error. I know that the code could be optimized, but I'm wondering where should I dispose of the object _resizedImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time that ResizeImage is called, you create a new Bitmap. This Bitmap should be Disposed as soon as you know that it is not needed anymore. It seems that you don't need the resized image after you've drawn it on the Graphics. Therefore I suggest the following change:

```
public static void DrawOnPanel(Graphics g)
{
    using (Image_resizedImage = ResizeImage(Resources.myImage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(_resizedImage, destX, destY);
    }
    // resizedImage is Disposed

    // ... several other images resized & manipulated then drawn
}
```

### Room for improvement

Your current design will create a new Resized Bitmap every time `DrawOnPanel` is called. It seems to me that most of time that Resources.myImage is resized the resized Bitmap will be the same. Why don't you just remember it until the parameters that influence the resized Bitmap are changed?

If I look at the code it seems that you always create the same resized image from an original image. So you could even put all your resized images into one Dictionary for fast lookup:

```
// get all Image resources that you will resize and put them in a Dictionary
// Key original Bitmap, Value: resized Bitmap
private Dictionary<Bitmap, BitMap> images = this.FetchImages()
    .ToDictionary(
       // Parameter keySelector: key is original image
       image => image,
       // Parameter valueSelector: value is the resized image
       imgage => ResizeImage(original));
```

Displaying the resized images will now be much faster: only a Lookup.

```
public static void DrawOnPanel(Graphics g)
{
    var _resizedImage = this.Images[Resources.myImage];
    g.DrawImage(_resizedImage, destX, destY);
   // ... several other images resized & manipulated then drawn
}
```

Don't forget to Dispose the bitmaps when your Form is Closed, or at its latest when your Form is Disposed:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        foreach (var resizedImage in images.Values)
            resizedImage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the concrete suggestions! I used the `using` statement to dispose of my image just like you wrote, but I get an error System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' Hovering over the _resizedImage in Visual Studio it appears to be disposed. Could the problem be that the method is static?
As for the other improvements you suggested, they seem reasonable and I will try to implement them, thanks! Regards

Comment: "could the problem be that the method is static?" Well I guess you already tried it with a non-static method and you already tried it with a dummy image that isn't resized, haven't you? And what if you just create a copy of your original image in the using statement? There are so many things you could have tried in about the time it took me to type this reply

Comment: By the way: it could also be that the Bitmap is already disposed. Wrap your resized Bitmap into a child class of Bitmap and override the `protected virtual void Dispose(bool)`. Put a breakpoint to see when the Dispose is called

Comment: I've already tried your first 2 suggestions and no luck. I'll try the other stuff you've suggested and dig deeper into my code. Regards

Comment: Note that images fetched from the resources probably make a new instance each time too, so you may need to change any use of `Resources.myImage` to its own bitmap variable, in its own using block, so as `using (Bitmap resBm = Resources.myImage) using (Image_resizedImage = ResizeImage(resBm)) { ... }`.